# Logic for filtering dependent on two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am struggling to write the right logic to filter two columns based only on the condition in one column. I have multiple ids and if an id appears in 2020, I want all the data for the other years that id was measured to come along.

As an example, if a group contains the number 3, I want all the values in that group. We should end up with a dataframe with all the b and d rows.

```
df4 <- data.frame(group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
                        "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d"),
                  pop = c(1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  value  = c(1,2,3,2.5,2,2,3,4,3.5,3,3,2,1,2,2.5,0.5,1.5,6,2,1.5)) 

threes <- df4 %>%
   filter(pop == 3 |&ifelse????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit slower than the other answers here (more steps involved), but for me a bit clearer:

```
df4 %>% 
  filter(pop == 3) %>% 
  distinct(group) %>% 
  pull(group) -> groups

df4 %>% 
  filter(group %in% groups)
```

or if you want to combine the two steps:

```
df4 %>% 
  filter(group %in% df4 %>% 
           filter(pop == 3) %>% 
           distinct(group) %>% 
           pull(group))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```r
df4[df4$group %in% df4$group[df4$pop == 3],]
#>    group pop value
#> 6      b   1   2.0
#> 7      b   2   3.0
#> 8      b   3   4.0
#> 9      b   4   3.5
#> 10     b   5   3.0
#> 16     d   1   0.5
#> 17     d   2   1.5
#> 18     d   3   6.0
#> 19     d   4   2.0
#> 20     d   5   1.5
```

Comment: Base R FTW! I personally find it a little easier to read using `with` (though no nchars are saved): `df4[with(df4, group %in% group[pop == 3]), ]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way using dplyr group_by(), filter() and any() function combined. any() will return TRUE for the matching condition. Group by will do the operation for each subgroup of the variable you mention as a grouping.
Follow these steps:

1. First pipe the data to group_by() to group by your group variable.
2. Then pipe to filter() to filter by if any group pop is equal to 3 using any() function.

```
df4 <- data.frame(group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
                            "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d"),
                  pop = c(1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  value  = c(1,2,3,2.5,2,2,3,4,3.5,3,3,2,1,2,2.5,0.5,1.5,6,2,1.5)) 
# load the library
library(dplyr)

threes <- df4 %>% 
group_by(group) %>%  
filter(any(pop == 3))
# print the result
threes
```

Output:

```r
threes
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
   group   pop value
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 b         1   2  
 2 b         2   3  
 3 b         3   4  
 4 b         4   3.5
 5 b         5   3  
 6 d         1   0.5
 7 d         2   1.5
 8 d         3   6  
 9 d         4   2  
10 d         5   1.5
```

Comment: How is this different from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65298399/1270695)?

Comment: I didn't notice others were writing answer until I figured it out this logic by myself. By coincidence, our logic is the same. I've tried to explain more elaborately how to use the code and tested my codes to make sure this works the way asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

An easy base R option is using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  df4,
  ave(pop == 3, group, FUN = any)
)
```

which gives

```
   group pop value
6      b   1   2.0
7      b   2   3.0
8      b   3   4.0
9      b   4   3.5
10     b   5   3.0
16     d   1   0.5
17     d   2   1.5
18     d   3   6.0
19     d   4   2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dplyr:

```
df4%>%group_by(group)%>%filter(any(pop==3))
```